# Error: Failed to resolve: spotify-android-auth:1.0.0: ; Has anyone had this error and do you know how to correct it?

Tags: android, android-studio, spotify, android-studio-3.0, libspotify

Really struggling to figure out exactly what is going on here. Just trying to get the spoitfy api to work in android studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Ynm.jpg

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The right dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.spotify.android:auth:1.0.0-alpha'
compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b@aar'
```

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk)

Comment: Thanks, I had done it exactly as the documenation stated in the past, but still get that second Error : Failed to resolve: com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b:

Comment: As the documentation says you have to copy the spotify-player-*.aar file to your app folder

Comment: The documentation says to put in your App-> Libs folder. If you take a look at the screen shot in my OP, you can see that it is in fact in that folder.   Still a bit confused as to why this isn't working. Thanks for the reply though